# How do I add a Google Chrome plugin from my website to a browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension

I have created a plugin.  In that I have taken a folder and that folder contains an `HTML page`, `manifest file`, `image` and a `.js` file.  Then I am loading the extension from load unpacked extensions from the Google Chrome extensions settings.  Then the plugin is added to Chrome.

I have then packed the extension and I have gotten a `.crx` file and `.pem` file.  I have dragged that file in to the Chrome folder and it is also adding it to Chrome.

I am including that file in a download link on my website like:

```
       <a href="@Url.Content("../test.crx")" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

And added the mime file type extension in the `web.config` file like:

```
 <system.webServer>   
    <staticContent>
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".crx" mimeType="application/x-chrome-extension" />
    </staticContent>
 </system.webServer>
```

Now the file is downloading on link button click and it is getting an error:
`Apps,extensions and user scripts cannot be added from this website.` 
My website is not live yet, I am using only localhost.  How can I rectify this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can not trigger installation through `<a href="@Url.Content("../test.crx")"`

- You should have a link tag `<link rel="chrome-webstore-item"
  href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf">`
- You can trigger installation through `chrome.webstore.install(url, successCallback, failureCallback)`

For more information check [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation).